# Generating MIN, AVG, MAX columns from a column. [SQL] Hive

Tags: sql, database, hive, bigdata

I have a database with a column for oil prices.
My goal is to generate a table with columns showing Min Price, AvgPrice, and Max Price based off of the Oil value column grouped by location. Where oil.frequency = 'A'

this is my current query

```
select location, 
       min(oil.value) over (partition BY oil.location), 
       max(oil.value) over (partition BY oil.location), 
       avg(oil.value) over (partition BY oil.location)
FROM OIL 
Where oil.frequency = 'A'
GROUP BY oil.location, oil.value;
```

The images below show my data table and the 2nd image shows how I want the data to appear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPAjQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGMdq.png)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need window functions.
Just group by location and aggregate:

```
select location, 
       min(value), 
       max(value), 
       avg(value)
FROM OIL 
Where frequency = 'A'
GROUP BY location;
```